# CI: Making a class that could be accesed by multiple controllers?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making website, that will be used by 2 different user types. And both types have different controllers. But some things are common for both users, specifically I want to make a class that will contain methods that will be run when either user logs in (it will check some stuff like is email confirmed etc etc..)

Anyway, I tried to create new library, and that worked sort of.. But there are problems because $this is not available, and I need to use $CI, which needs to be redeclared on every method.. so it is a bit of a pain.

Any better way to do it?

Comment: Why use completely different controllers instead of some logic for different user types that load different views or data etc... so common functions are simple?

Comment: @RyanKempt, initially I was gonna go with that.. But they ways in which the users will use site will be too different.. So the controller would be way too messy. 2 separate controllers in this instance was the cleaner solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the Controller class. Have a look here:

[Codeigniter MY_Controller](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/MY_Controller_-_how_to_extend_the_CI_Controller/)